# Node JS app server deployment

Tags: node.js, deployment, server, nodes

I have a dedicated Godaddy server.
I need to run a node app on it. 
I can do that by SSH running

```
node app.js
```

The problem is that when the ssh connection is disconnected ... The app stops working.

How do I run it so that it does not stops.

Answer (score 0):

Create a shell script (eg. **yourScript.sh**), and put your command "**node app.js**" inside.

Example **yourScript.sh**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
node app.js
```

Make sure you have execute permission:

```
chmod +x yourScript.sh
```

Then run with:

```
nohup ./yourScript.sh &
```

This will mean the process doesn't exit when you disconnect. **Nohup** catches the HUP signals. Nohup doesn't put the job automatically in the background. We need to tell that explicitly using **&**

Comment: will it also run if the server is rebooted ??

Comment: @SatyamSaxena - no, if you reboot it won't restart. What OS are you running (godaddy server) ?  Your question only asked how to prevent the process dying when you disconnect your SSH session. For auto-restart, you just need to execute the shell script using whatever OS specific startup hook is provided by that OS.

Comment: @SatyamSaxena - have updated the answer to provide you with little information on creating the shell script. How are you getting on?

Answer (score 0):

I use [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) to run Node.js app in production. It has convenient command line API to show status of the process, start/stop it, allows restart on reboot, etc.

Config file looks like this:

```
[program:myapp]
directory=/home/myapp/app/current
command=node server/index.js
autostart=true  
autorestart=true  
environment=
  PORT=3000,
  MY_ANOTHER_VAR="something"
stderr_logfile=/var/log/myapp.err.log  
stdout_logfile=/var/log/myapp.out.log  
user=myapp
```